# GNS3 windows XP appliance shows blue screen

Tags: windows-xp, bsod, vmware-workstation, tightvnc

[image]

I have added a windows xp appliance to GNS3 from a working copy of a vmdk file after configuring the image as required but if open the console (TightVNC) as depicted above I am unexpectedly shocked to see the blue screen of death (depicted below). I assume this has to deal with the fact that the hardware configuration on the GNS3 for the appliance needs to be tweaked.

[image]

I have opened the same image in the vmware workstation as depicted below to find it working just fine:

[image]

What is needed to have the windows xp appliance successfully boot up in the console (TightVNC) window of the GNS3 simulator?

Comment: review some comments here regarding 0x0000007b error on this issue here:

https://www.gns3.com/qa/windows-xp-appliance-shows-blue-

Comment: I am downloading the windows 8.1 image which consumes so much more system resources and will test it as I have described in my comment of this post: 

https://www.gns3.com/discussions/gns3-windows-qemu-appliance-now-

Comment: I still would like to know a solution for my original question as Win XP is much lighter than windows 8.1 so for the super user community out there, please give me your insights on this

Answer (score -1):

VMware Workstation and QEMU emulate & virtualize different hardware.  Since XP is so old, it can rarely recover from a major subsystem change.

First thing to try is removing the VMware Tools from the XP image while it's running in Workstation.  This should remove any VMware specific drivers and may allow the system to boot.

If that doesn't work, you will likely need to do a repair installation of XP.

Boot from your XP CD-ROM, when you get to the setup screen, you want to press enter, not R.  Follow the setup wizard, when you are prompted the second time to do a repair, press R, setup will detect the correct hardware and install the necessary drivers. 
Illustrated repair: https://www.wikihow.com/Do-a-Windows-XP-%22Repair-Install%22